# Why do I lose data speed on my desktop (WLAN) without loosing signal?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, internet

I am running Windows 7 SP1 and I’ve just bought a Wi-Fi card (plugged in pci on my motherboard) for my desktop. My wireless adapter is a [300Mbps Wireless N PCI Adapter
TL-WN851ND](http://www.tp-link.fr/products/details/?model=TL-WN851ND#over) ([US TP-Link page in English](http://www.tp-link.us/products/details/?categoryid=&model=TL-WN851ND))

The signal is always between 80% and 100% according to Windows and the tool of my receiver. But sometimes I lose all the bandwidth. I’m still able to ping (both other devices and google), but the connection has not enough power to load a simple webpage.

It only occurs with this desktop, all my laptops and phones work perfectly.

From what I already know: It is not DNS related—I can ping Google—and I have no signal problem the connection my Internet provider gives me is sufficient for the test I run; 80Mbps is enough to load a webpage.

My guess is that I noticed something odd. When I launch my Torrent app to download Linux distribution and set a very low DL limit (25kbps) I never have such outages, so I’m afraid it could be related to some power saving mode.

The problem is that I’ve disabled this power saving mode on my Wi-Fireceiver and I can’t find anything related to it in my bios.

My guess may be wrong, but that’s all I’ve got.

Comment: *"I am running Windows 6 SP1"* -- What is Win **6**?  @JakeGould -- If you're going to edit other people's posts, don't add misinformation or change the tone.

Comment: @sawdust I wouldn't say a typo counts as "misinformation". :)

Comment: krowarfr never mentioned his router, just the adapter card TL-WN851ND (name's even in the url). Where did that TP-Link AC1750 extra info come from? Editing's supposed to fix errors...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess...

How do the ping times change when things slow down? Constant 30-100ms? Or do they slow to 3,000-10,000ms or start getting dropped packets? Ping times to your router would check your local wifi connection & router responsiveness, pinging google would do that plus everthing out to google's side of the internet. If ping times don't slow down, maybe it's just a part/branch of your internet that's slowing down for other reasons.

I can sometimes overwhelm my router (or maybe wifi) especially torrents. Things bog down and slow a LOT if there's just too many connections for things to handle. When that happens ping times slow waaaaaaay down.  Limiting the number of connections might help.

Sometimes wifi is just unreliable too, maybe interference from microwaves, motors, anything, they're just radio waves.

And maybe your wifi isn't truthfully reporting the actual signal strength, I had an adapter once that only showed +60%, but would drop below that. It's 60% was really about 10%.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. When things slow down the ping remqins quite good.

And when I use torrent things don't get worth but seem to get better...